# How can I verify that a file follows the pattern: "real_number:real_number: ... :real_number:"?

Tags: bash

I need to check that a file follows a struture like this before using it

```
1:15:0:.0504:.1092:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:
2:15:1:0:0:.0504:.0504:0:0:0:0:0:0:3:.345:3.4:
hello
3:5:0:0:0:0:0:hello:0:0:0:0:0:
5:13:1:0:-3:0:0:.0378:0:0:0:0:0:
6:10:0:0:0:0:0:.0540:0:0:.0840:0:343:345:32:33:.1:
```

Where each real number is separated by ":"

```
pattern="^(-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?(:[0-9]*(\.[0-9]*)*)*):$"

while IFS= read -r linea; do
    if [[ -n $linea ]]; then
        if [[ $linea =~ $pattern ]]; then
            echo "Valid line: $linea"
        else
            echo "Invalid line: $linea"
        fi
    fi
done < "$file"
```

Outputs:

```
Valid line: 1:15:0:.0504:.1092:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:
Valid line: 2:15:1:0:0:.0504:.0504:0:0:0:0:0:0:3:.345:3.4:
Invalid line: hello
Invalid line: 3:5:0:0:0:0:0:hello:0:0:0:0:0:
Invalid line: 5:-13:1:0:0:0:0:.0378:0:0:0:0:0:
Valid line: 6:10:0:0:0:0:0:.0540:0:0:.0840:0:343:345:32:33:.1:
```

And all lines should be valid except 3 and 4

Comment: `^(-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+:)+$` seems a better choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Since your subject line says you want to match

```
the pattern: "real_number:real_number: ... :real_number:"
```

and given your current regexp, this might be adequate for your needs, using any awk:

```
$ awk '{print (/^((-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|\.[0-9]+):)+$/ ? "Valid" : "Invalid"), "line:", $0}' file
Valid line: 1:15:0:.0504:.1092:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:
Valid line: 2:15:1:0:0:.0504:.0504:0:0:0:0:0:0:3:.345:3.4:
Invalid line: hello
Invalid line: 3:5:0:0:0:0:0:hello:0:0:0:0:0:
Valid line: 5:13:1:0:-3:0:0:.0378:0:0:0:0:0:
Valid line: 6:10:0:0:0:0:0:.0540:0:0:.0840:0:343:345:32:33:.1:
```

or either of these:

- `awk '{print (/^((-?[0-9]+)?(\.[0-9]+)?:)+$/ ? "Valid" : "Invalid"), "line:", $0}' file`
- `awk '{print (/^((-?[0-9]+)?(\.[0-9]+)?:)+$/ && !/(^|:):/ ? "Valid" : "Invalid"), "line:", $0}' file`

Comment: first alternative is incorrect since everything is optional: `:::`

Comment: @jhnc are you refering to the last 2 scripts in my answer? If so the first of those 2 would allow `:::` which is why I provided the second one that won't allow it so the OP can decide which is adequate for their possible input.

Comment: I didn't initially spot the second test because of the linewrap on my screen

Comment: any reason to allow positive decimal without leading digit but not negative?

Comment: fraction not decimal: `.1:` vs `-.1:`

Comment: Oh, I see. No reason I'm aware of but maybe the OP never has that in their input (since it's not in their example) and so don't care to handle it or maybe they want to disallow it? idk...